# How to define a map with a specific type key and any single type value in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections

What I need is something like

```
Map[DateTime, Any]
```

but all the values must be of any *one specific type*. For example it is not to be that one value is an Int, another is a Double and the third is a String - all the records are to be of the same specific type downcasted to Any.

I am going to take the map as an argument into a semi-type-agnostic function, determine the type with match/case and perform a particular algorithm. The function is actually going to support *some* types and throw an exception if the type provided is not supported.

Comment: I bet some clever use of [Manifest](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest) can cause compiler errors for unsupported types instead of runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want; you seem to want something that is almost exactly what generics do, but apparently with some difference in the details that I haven't understood.  So I'll guess:

If your complaint is that maps' add can widen the type of values:

```
scala> val m = Map(5 -> "fish")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(5 -> fish)


scala> m + ("foo" -> "dish")  // Type mismatch on key
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
 required: (Int, ?)
              m + ("foo" -> "dish")

scala> m + (2 -> 44)  // Type mismatch on value
m + (2 -> 44)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Any] = Map(5 -> fish, 2 -> 44)
```

then you can use generics and multiple arguments to thwart changes to the type of the value in methods you provide:

```
def add[A,B](m: Map[A,B])(a: A, b: B) = m + (a -> b)


scala> add(m)(2, 44) 
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(44)
 required: java.lang.String
              add(m)(2, 44)
```

Here, the types of `A` and `B` are bound to whatever is in the map before it reaches the second parameter block.  So you won't have to worry about contravariance of the map value type.

Comment: I know about generics, but I don't want `def semiAgnostic[A](m: Map[DateTime,A])` in this case. I want `def semiAgnostic(m: Map[DateTime,A]):Map[DateTime,B]` where A is to be detected automatically inside the function and B is to be detected automatically inside whatever function further consumes the result. Using match/case to specialize from Any makes such an approach possible but in this case `Map[DateTime,Any]` would allow unexpected sets in (while constrainting input as strongly as possible is always desired).

Comment: The API consumer is to be able to use the function simply by calling it as `semiAgnostic(in: Map[DateTime,Int])` or `semiAgnostic(in: Map[DateTime,Double])` or `semiAgnostic(in: Map[DateTime,SomeCutomClass])` without specifying the value type as [A]. This is a problem of usability: the DSL needs to be as readable and redundancy-free as possible as the audience is not meant to be constrainted by programming experience requirements.

Comment: I am curious if a type can be used as a parameter, not a specifier. `Something[A]`, `Something[B]` and simply `Something` being different types instead of one type with a type specifier as a property seem to limit flexibility significantly.

Comment: Scala's type inference will already infer the A in your example.

Comment: @Ivan - Your comments don't make sense to me, at least not if we're talking about Scala.  You are _probably_ misunderstanding something, but I can't be sure.  It seems like you've complained that you don't want generics because you want something that works like generics, and that the API consumer has to be able to call the functions the way they can with generics, except that you think generics are a problem.

Comment: I just point that specifying a type as a separate argument can be considered redundant as the type can be determined from an object passed as Any. A user is not to have to write something like `def myFunction[T](a:T,b:T); val a:Int=1; val b:Int=2; myFunction[Int](a, b)` - but he is to write `myFunction(a, b)` and the function is to determine `a` and `b` types and throw if there are not the same (which is possible by means of pattern matching without generics). In my case I need a Map that will throw if a second/3rd/etc tuple added is not exactly the same type as the first which was added.

Comment: Anyway I've already figured the solution out theoretically (I think it is easy to implement extending a Map) but have chosen to use generics to keep it simple and concise from the inside too, not only from the outside.

Comment: @Ivan - Why would the user write `myFunction[Int](a,b)`?  The compiler infers the `[Int]` from the type of `a` and `b`.  Why would the user _not_ write `def myFunction[T](a: T, b: T)` and still expect that `a` and `b` are the same type?  You continue to not make sense to me.

Comment: I don't mean it literally, it's just to illustrate the concept.

Comment: Would you mind me editing your answer to make it a formally correct answer to the question? I've added a sentence to the top of it. Delete it if you don't agree. If it's ok, I will accept the answer in this version to close the question constructively and logically consistently.

Comment: @Ivan - I still don't understand what you want, so no, I don't like the edit.  I'll modify the wording; maybe that version will be okay with you.

Comment: @Ivan - I had another guess at what you meant--did I guess correctly this time?

Comment: No, that's not as the first example derives the type ("String") at compile time. And though it works with `val=...`, the Map won't necessarily fit into a target function as its argument. "want something that is almost exactly what generics do, but " - what I want is something that is almost exactly what generics do, but without any [T] argument being required to be ever specified. All the types are to be figured out at runtime, through reflection. I could just use Any, but this would let all the values be of different types, which is not desired.

Comment: To illustrate (not intended to work, but, I hope, going to explain the intention) - something like `f[T = typeof(v)](dt: DateTime, v: T):Map[DateTime, T]` (where T can be left unspecified to be derived from the `v` argument got).

Comment: @Ivan - You mean you want Scala to act like a weakly typed language and throw a runtime exception if it ends up with a map where later values are not the same type or subtypes of the first value entered?

Comment: Kind of like that. But this behaviour is possible to achieve on JVM without actual weak typing as we have Scala `Any` and Java `Object` reference types. I suppose such a technique could had some active usage in Java 1.4 and older (where there were no generics in the language).

Comment: @Ivan - That's _exactly how the compiler fills in the type `T` already_!  You are asking for _what you have already got_ and the examples I gave in my current answer demonstrate this.  Apparently you want something that you are not asking for.  Please modify your question to include an exact copy of code that you want to compile and doesn't, or code that you want to throw an error that compiles and runs without complaint.

Comment: Holy lizards! That works! pastebin.com/m7U3GrxT The problem that made me to raise the question is that I could never imagine that [T] can be left unspecified (I've once tried with no success - seems I was just doing it wrong). So I was thinking the `Any` way, looking for some crutches to make it to behave like generics do instead of like it does naturally. Thank you so immensely much - you've done pretty a job teaching me today, I owe you a huge beer... :-) Scala can't stop surprising me with its beauty all the way I am exploring it...